# Change property from setter and notify

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

Within a property's setter, sometimes I must change the property's value to something other than the one currently being set.  This doesn't work by simply raising the `PropertyChanged` event, for a Windows Store app anyway.  I can change the value, but the UI doesn't update itself based on that change.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The view-model:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if ( text != value ) {
                text = value == "0" ? "" : value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

I wrote the following method which fixes this problem fairly well:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged_Delayed( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
{
    Task.Delay( 1 ).ContinueWith(
        t => OnPropertyChanged( propertyName ),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
}
```

I call this instead of `OnPropertyChanged`.  But I recently discovered an intermittent bug in my Windows Store app caused by the `OnPropertyChanged_Delayed` call occurring after the user has navigated away from the page.  This leads me to seek an alternative solution.

Is there a better way to change a property's value from within its setter and notify the UI of the change?  I am currently developing a Windows Store app, so I'd like an answer in that context.  But I will eventually port it to UWP.  Is this also a problem on UWP?  If so, I'd like a solution there as well (which may be the same).

Comment: So your viewmodel, I am assuming, fires the event and your screen captures the event but that screen has been navigated away from?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, the view-model fires the event from within the property's setter under those circumstances.

Comment: I mean why do you need `OnPropertyChanged_Delayed`? this is a code smell. if you want to notify property changed then just notify. why make it delayed?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Did you read the first paragraph of my question?

Comment: @HappyNomad While you say that "sometimes I must change the property's value to something other than the one currently being set", you do not give an explanation why firing the PropertyChanged event should be delayed. The answer given by Mark shows how to do it synchronously.

Comment: I did read your question. but I did not understand why you need to do that. This is XY problem. i.e you are not solving the root of the problem. but just patching your code just to make it work _somehow_.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary What is "the root of the problem" in your opinion?

Comment: so you have a race condition on setting your property? is there another control trying to change the property but you want to change it too? you should block the event handlers of that controller when you are changing the value. the cheapest way I can give is to use Boolean helper value to check if property must be notified or not. ( the root of the problem is, you shouldn't set the property in the first place, when you don't want it.)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No and no.  I will update my question shortly.

Comment: I've run into this problem many times with the SelectedItem property of a ComboBox.  Most WPF objects work fine when your property setter overrides a new property value that's coming from the binding target.  But ComboBox.SelectedItem does not; if you don't delay the PropertyChanged event, then the view will ignore your ViewModel's value and display whatever value it was originally trying to set.

Comment: @RogerN Yes, I also use my `OnPropertyChanged_Delayed` for `SelectedItem` in some cases.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I added a simple example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Clemens I added a simple example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was: from within a property's setter, how to change the value being set and have the UI recognize that change?

The two-way XAML binding assumes that the target value which is set to the source, is also the value that is actually stored by the source.  It ignores the `PropertyChanged` event of the property it just set, and so it doesn't check the source's actual value after updating it.

### TextBox

The simplest solution is: make the binding one-way, and instead update the source in a `TextChanged` handler.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

The event handler:

```
void TextBox_TextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    var pm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    pm.Text = tb.Text; //update one-way binding's source
}
```

When the UI's text changes, the event is handled by setting the view-model's text.  The view text's one-way binding means that it then receives the value that was actually set.  Doing things this way avoids the limitation of XAML bindings mentioned above.

It's possible to leave the binding as two-way and the above solution still works.  But if you want to let the two-way binding update its source, then the code is slightly longer:

```
void TextBox_TextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    var pm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    tb.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty ).UpdateSource();
    if ( tb.Text != pm.Text )
        tb.Text = pm.Text; //correct two-way binding's target
}
```

If you don't need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` then another alternative is:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

with the event handler:

```
void TextBox_LostFocus( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    var pm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    tb.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty ).UpdateSource();
    pm.OnPropertyChanged( "Text" );
}
```

### ComboBox

@RogerN's answer was helpful for showing that the problem can be overcome using `SelectionChanged`, but he doesn't actually show how to change the value within the setter.  I will show that here.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Add this property to the view-model:

```
public IList<string> Items
{
    get { return items; }
}
readonly IList<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string> { "first", "second", "third", "forth" };
```

Within the `Text` property's setter, change the value like this:

```
text = value == "third" ? "forth" : value;
```

The first approach for `TextBox` shown above doesn't work for `ComboBox`, but the second one does.

```
void ComboBox_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    var cb = (ComboBox)sender;
    var pm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    cb.GetBindingExpression( ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty ).UpdateSource();
    if ( (string)cb.SelectedItem != pm.Text )
        cb.SelectedItem = pm.Text; //correct two-way binding's target
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I explained in my comment above, I've run into this sort of problem when dealing with the ComboBox control.  I want to change the value of the selected item in the setter, but the view ignores my new value.  Delaying the PropertyChanged event is an ugly workaround that can cause unintended side effects.

But another way to get around the issue is to bind the SelectionChanged event to a command in your view model.

This XAML binds to the SelectedItem as usual, but also uses System.Windows.Interactivity to bind the SelectionChanged event:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

In your view model, don't try to override the selected value in the setter.  Instead, change it in the ICommand implementation:

```
string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
    }
}

// RelayCommand is just a custom ICommand implementation which calls the specified delegate when the command is executed
public RelayCommand SelectionChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(unused =>
        {
            if (_selectedItem == MyItems[2])
                _selectedItem = MyItems[0];
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem"));
        });
    }
}
```

As I said, I've only observed this behavior for the SelectedItem property.  If you're having trouble with a TextBox then you might try changing the UpdateSourceTrigger of the binding like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdatedSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```

Comment: See my answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in UWP without issue.  I don't know of a Windows Store App differing in any way.

```
private string _informativeMessage;
public string InformativeMessage
{
    get { return _informativeMessage; }
    set
    {
        if (_informativeMessage != value)
        {
            if(value == SomeValueThatMakesMeNeedToChangeIt)
            {
                _informativeMessage = "Overridden Value";
            }
            else
            {
                _informativeMessage = value;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

What does your property look like?

Comment: The issue occurs with two-way bindings for `TextBox.Text` and `Selector.SelectedItem`.

Comment: If you could post the pertinent code, I may be able to help more.

Comment: I added a simple example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: For what it is worth... in UWP, this works as expected if you use x:Bind as opposed to Binding.  I'm not suggesting that is a solution... just pointing out a difference.  It looks like you have a couple methods that can be used to accomplish your goal.